# How to write route with measure to PostGIS with FME?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, file-geodatabase, fme-form, linear-referencing

I have calibrated route in file geodatabase (ArcGIS). I have line coordinate (kilometre) in the start and the end point.
I try export this route with M-value to PostGIS in FME.
But in result I have line without M-value.
Do you know how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this works not out of the box but I'm not sure why. Two possible alternative ways to do this:

1. Use a SQLCreator to create the table.
2. Write the result to PostGIS table A. Read from table, merge the measures to the features and write to PostGIS table B. I don't understand why, but this works.